# Sql Matching exact DataSets on same table

Tags: sql, merge, correlated-subquery

I have a table that contains data such as:

```
Store,Product
a,         1
a,         2
b,         3
b,         2
c,         3
c,         1
d,         1
d,         2
d,         3
```

I am trying to write a query that gives me the Replacement Store, so since store d sells all the product that store a sells it could be a replacement for store a but store a could not be a replacement for store d since it does not have all of the product store d sells.

So the query would  return the following table:

```
Store,Store Replacement
a,-         
b,-     
c,- 
d,a
```

*Note i couldn't figure out how to make a table, so a ',' represents a separation of columns. - equals a blank in the space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that does work:

```
select sp.store, sp2.store
from (select sp.*, count(*) over (partition by store) as numproducts
      from @storeproduct sp
     ) sp join
     @storeproduct sp2
     on sp.product = sp2.product and sp.store <> sp2.store
group by sp.store, sp2.store, numproducts
having count(sp2.product) = numproducts;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/1698) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I really like your answer, as I have never used the partition or having commands, i do have one question though, if the product column was the id or a string  you were trying to find it by matching those, how would you do it? I don't see how I can make it work with count(*)

Comment: @Chadbur . . . I don't understand the question.  The `count(*)` isn't looking at columns, so it doesn't care what the types of the columns are.

Comment: You'll have to excuse me i didn't understand what the count(*) was doing or how it was used, but it worked, ill have to spend sometime understanding how exactly its working.

Comment: @Chadbur . . . In this query, it adds a new column which is the number of products in the store.